# How to use PHPExcel plugin in a Symfony 2.3 Action Controller

Tags: php, symfony, phpexcel

I'd like to know if anyone could help me in using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) plugin in my Symfony action controller.

I need to generate the Excel file and let the user download it. But at Symfony2 I can't access the plugin directly.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your composer.json file, and add the following two lines under the requires section:

```
"require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-develop",
    "wisembly/excelant": "*"
},
```

Then run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will install both phpexcel and the ExcelAnt wrapper. ExcelAnt makes dealing with PHPExcel trivial. If you need more help, add a comment and I'll update this answer!

Comment: But I should put it at the composer.json of the root or in the bundle? And then update composer (php composer.phar update)?

Those lines will download the PHPExcel and ExcelAnt wrapper and put in the project?

Comment: Correct, put it in the root (of your app) composer.json file. Running composer.phar update will automatically download and set everything up for you.

Comment: First Excel lib out of a dozen that actually installs for me. This deserves a star already.

Comment: Hello! I used this way you mentioned. Now can you please help me on how to use this library in my controller? Please let me know asap. Thnx

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes please see the ExcelAnt tutorial - https://github.com/Wisembly/ExcelAnt

Answer (score 2):

Hm, try [**ExcelBundle**](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle), it is easy to use.

**Updade**

If you use symfony 2.3 just install with next instruction:

[**INSTALLATION with COMPOSE**](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle#installation-with-composer)

Thats all, you can use all services of this bundle in any controller in any bundle in your project. If bundle enable, it services available in all bundles in your project.

And read next for best understanding [**Service Container**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: I saw this bundle. But didn't understand how to install it at Symfony. Because at the usage section of the readme, it instructs to put ask the service 'xls.service_xls5' for example. But the service is in ExcelBundle, and the controller that need to generate the Excel is in another bundle.
Sorry for my poor knowledge. I'm yet a newbie at Symfony.